# Export to wide screen (16:9) from Final Cut pro X

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, aspect

Apologies for the noob question but I've just started trying to learn FCP and couldn't find the settings to export my movie in 16:9 aspect ratio.

Can anyone tell me the quickest way to go about it?
(source material has a variety of different aspect ratios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer assumes that the video that you're editing is already in a 16:9 ratio, otherwise when you export there will be black bars on the sides or above and below your video.

A 16:9 ratio is the standard for HDTV and Full HD. You're probably familiar with the Youtube video qualities - 360p, 480p, 720p, 1080p, etc. These are all 16:9. Therefore, all you have to do is export in one of these resolutions - 1080p is Full HD and 720p is HD.

For more reading on common aspect ratios, reference this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16:9#Common_resolutions).

Comment: Thanks. I'm away from my FCP machine just now but will hopefully be able to have a look later on tonight.

Comment: Finally got a chance to fire up FCP and noticed it's in the initial project set up requester.